# Are RenderFragments required in order to have nested components/elements?

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0

I am pretty new to Blazor and I currently have a parent component called `ModuleConfig` which essentially serves as a row and then it would have config items inside it. What I want to achieve is to place components inside it without having to create a `RenderFragment` (`ConfigContent`) as follows:

```
<ModuleConfig>
    <ConfigContent>
        <ModuleConfigColumnDesc Label=@localizer["CorporateDataHeader"]
                                Description=@localizer["CorporateDataDescription"] />
        <ModuleConfigColumnContent>

        </ModuleConfigColumnContent>
    </ConfigContent>
</ModuleConfig>
```

What I want is:

```
<ModuleConfig>
    <ModuleConfigColumnDesc Label=@localizer["CorporateDataHeader"]
                            Description=@localizer["CorporateDataDescription"] />
    <ModuleConfigColumnContent>

    </ModuleConfigColumnContent>
</ModuleConfig>
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: This looks like a grid/table. the problem in being too abstract is you loose meaning to readers who aren't intimate with what you want.  The answer is probably yes, but it's not going to written in two minutes, and I don't want to waste time writing an answer that totally misses your intended mark.  Can you be a bit more "concrete" on what `ModuleConfig` may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by giving the name `ChildContent` to a `RenderFragment` parameter.

`SomeComponent.razor`

```
@ChildContent

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent {get; set;} 
}
```

Passing content directly into the component:

```
<SomeComponent>
    <div>
        Child content here!
    </div>
</SomeComponent>
```

In this example, everything between the `SomeComponent` tags are passed in.

The docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#child-content-render-fragments

Example fiddle: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/p2shf41t

Comment: if i understand the question correctly it was about not using a Renderfragment.

Comment: @jeb depends on how you interpret the question. My answer helps OP achieve what he wants - cleaner markup.

Comment: I would be surprised if someone wanted the functionality that render fragments give you without using render fragments

Comment: Yeah hard to say. I was thinking about a simple Forloop and a Paramter List<Child> in the parent Component, but it's not clear what the desired output is.

Comment: Gents, I think the question as it stands is too abstract.  We're making a lot of guesses.  It looks like a grid/tables, but I may be totally wrong.  I've added a comment asking for some more concrete info.  A possible answer is the registration implementation used by `QuickGrid`, but....

Comment: Sorry for the abstractness, essentially <ModuleConfig> renders into a <div> I just wanted to know if there was a cleaner way to have child content without having to define a renderfragment.

Comment: @KurtHamilton Has solved what I was looking to do. Is this available in .Net 6?

Comment: @leroyjenkinss24 yes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#child-content-render-fragments